# How to search two continuous elements in XML file

Tags: xml, informatica-powercenter

I have an XML file where each Client ID has two main elements EmailInfo and PhoneInfo and file has around 100k such clients, but the file is failing in other system due to missing tag of PhoneExt in some case.

How can I search if phone number closing tag and phone contact time code opening tag are present together below one of another.

```
<CXToCifConversionItem>
    <SrcSysCliId>02AC04</SrcSysCliId>
        <CXEmailInfo>
          <EmailAddrCntxtCd>H</EmailAddrCntxtCd>
          <EmailAddrStatCd>CX</EmailAddrStatCd>
          <EmailAddrNm>firstname.lastname@gmail.com</EmailAddrNm>
          <CXEmailUpdtTmstmp>2016-11-08 11:28:41.557000</CXEmailUpdtTmstmp>
        </CXEmailInfo>

        <CXPhonInfo>
          <PhonAddrCntxtCd>H</PhonAddrCntxtCd>
          <PhonTypCd>V</PhonTypCd>
          <PhonAreaCd>506</PhonAreaCd>
          <PhonNum>1234567</PhonNum>
          <PhonExtNum></PhonExtNum>
          <PhonCntctTmCd>EVE</PhonCntctTmCd>
          <PhonFrmtCd></PhonFrmtCd>
          <ForgnPhonNum></ForgnPhonNum>
          <CXPhonUpdtTmstmp>2003-01-29 17:58:06.197000</CXPhonUpdtTmstmp>
        </CXPhonInfo>
      </CXToCifConversionItem>
```

Answer (score 0):

In notepad++ you can search with regular expression :

```
</PhonNum>\x0D\x0A\ *<PhonCntctTmCd>
```

\x0D - matches carriage return character (CR, \r)

\x0A - matches linefeed character (LF, \n)

\ *  - matches zero or more space characters

Note that, if you are on Unix platform, you have to use only Linefeed.

Comment: </PhonNum>\x0D\x0A\ *<PhonCntctTmCd> I am not sure what does this expression translates to?if you can explain would be great

Comment: Updated with the explanation